# Einstein summation: power confusion

Tags: real-analysis, summation, tensors, convention, index-notation

Assuming $n_i = \sum_i n_i$ (Einstein summation). 
If I write $n_i^2$, does it mean

1. $(\sum_i n_i)^2$
2. $\sum_i (n_i^2)$

Is there a way to differentiate those two expressions clearly using Eistein summation?

Thank you :)

Comment: I would not define $n_i = \sum_i n_i$. Since I am not sure what you mean by the square of $n_i$.

Answer (score 1):

The Einstein summation convention can't be applied in your example because you only have one index variable ($i$). The convention applies to *repeated* indices, which is essentially how you avoid ambiguity.  So:
$$ \sum_i n_i^2 = n_1^2 +n_2^2 +n_3^2+\cdots$$
and 
$$ n_i^2 = n_i^2 $$ for each $i$ with no summation.  However,
$$ c^in_i^2 = \sum_i c^i n_i^2 = c^1n_1^2 +c^2n_2^2 + \cdots $$

Conventionally the summation uses a subscript and a superscript as it originally refers to co-variant and contra-variant vectors being summed.

You can also sum over more than one index this way:
$$c^ic^jn_in_j^2 = \sum_i \sum_j c^ic^jn_in_j^2 $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I still have a confusion regarding the Frobenius norm of a matrix. Considering this matrix norm as $f=tr(\bar{\bar{A}}^T\bar{\bar{A}})$. Using einstein summation, $f=A_{ij}^2$. Now consider the $A_{ij}$ coefficients are expressed as a sum over $k$ like $A_{ij}=n_{ijk}$. The frobenius norm will be then written $f=n_{ijk}^2$ which is wrong. To make it exact, we have to reintroduce the sum symbol like $f=(\sum_k n_{ijk})^2$

Comment: I don't understand your notation, but assuming you mean $\|A\|_F = \mathrm{trace }(A^T A)$ then this the sum of the squares of each element of $A^TA$ and would be written as $\|A\|_F = a_{ij}a^{ij} = \sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}a_{ij}$